# Import Excel to Auto-Identity Enabled Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to Import an Excel Sheet to an Auto Identity Enabled Table.

As Auto - Identity  ( Id Column ) is set to Not Null - I am not able to Import Excel Sheet.

How should i do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not map any Excel column to auto identity column in the table. That should help you to import the Excel sheet.